# How to correctly use Html.DropDownList with SelectList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm having an issue with using a SelectList with Html.DropDownList that I've been unable to solve by looking at answers to previous questions.

I have the following code in a View:

```
Dim myItems As New Collection
Dim thisItem As SelectListItem

For Each responsibility In Model.Responsibilities.EBS_Resonsibility

    thisItem = New SelectListItem
    thisItem.Text = responsibility.RESPONSIBILITY_NAME
    thisItem.Value = responsibility.RESPONSIBILITY_ID
    myItems.Add(thisItem)
Next
```

Which takes each item from my Model, turns it into a SelectListItem, and adds it to a collection.

Then I turn that into a SelectList:

```
Dim myRoles As New SelectList(myRoleItems, "Value", "Text")
```

And create my Html.DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleList", myRoles, "Select Role")
```

And finally handle it:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RoleHandler", "Account", New With {.RESPONSIBILITY_ID = myRoles.SelectedValue})">Search Buildings</a>
```

The problem is, nothing is getting passed. I know that my last line and my SelectList are correct, because if I add a parameter to the end of the SelectList for *selectedValue*, it will pass that parameter, like so:

```
Dim myRoles As New SelectList(myRoleItems, "Value", "Text", 905)
```

In that case, 905 gets passed. So, I'm fairly certain that I'm doing something wrong with accessing the Values from my SelectList in the DropDownList. The Names of the items display correctly in the DDL though, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Side note: `myRoleItems` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what is required by the `DropDownList()` method. Using `new SelectList(myRoleItems, "Value", "Text")` to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have for the anchor tag has some C# code, which gets executed on the server. Since the user can change the selected option of dropdown to something else at client side, you should handle this with client side javascript.

So set the href value of your link to the base url of the action method (without the route values) and give it an id which we will use to wire up some client side behavior.

```
@:<a id="myLink" href="@Url.Action("RoleHandler","Account")">Search Building</a>
```

Now have some javascript code to listen to the click event on this link, get the selected option from the dropdown and use that to build the new url.

```
@section scripts
   <script>
    $(function () {

        $("#myLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            url = url + "?RESPONSIBILITY_ID ="+$("#RoleList").val();
            window.location.href = url;
        });

    });
</script>
End Section
```

Also, you don't really need to create a new SelectList object, you can pass the list of SelectListItem to your `DropDownList` helper method.

```
Dim list = New List(Of SelectListItem)() From {
    New SelectListItem() With {
                        .Value = "a",
                        .Text = "a"
    },
    New SelectListItem() With {
                        .Value = "b",
                        .Text = "b"
    }
}
```

and

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleList", list, "Select Role")
```